# How is .htaccess still rewriting this?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite all but PHP files to a file.

I'm using htaccess, with the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.+\.(php)$ 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatcher.php [QSA,L]
```

Somehow, PHP files still get redirected to dispatcher.php.

How so? I can't get it.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should not leave any line break after a condition statement and the following rewriteRule in htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.+\.(php)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatcher.php [QSA,L]
```

Please try removing the empty line after `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.+\.(php)$`

Comment: Yep. Also, the problem is not that it doesn't work—problem is that it works too well! :-P

Comment: Do you have anything else in the htaccess file?

Comment: Hi Lepanto, thanks for your help. I have nothing else in the .htaccess file :-/